# mustache.js - issues in getting external template data using $get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mustache

js and i am getting external template using $get() method as shown below

```
function open_device_player(device_id)   
{
        var device_data={
                device_id:device_id
            };
        var n;
        $.get('js/temp.html', function(template, textStatus, jqXhr) {
                 n=Mustache.render($(template).filter('#pageTpl').html(), device_data);
                alert("inside get: "+n);
       });
        alert("outside get: "+n);
        $("body").append(n);

    }
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#videodiv_"+device_id );
    return false;
}
```

and this is my template file temp.html

```
<script id="pageTpl" type="text/template">
    <div data-role='page' id='videodiv_{{device_id}}'>
        <div data-role=header>
            <h1> Device Page </h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role=content>
            <img id='vid_{{device_id}}' src='http://localhost/mobilestreamvideo/mjpg/{{device_id}}' width='320'>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

My problem is i am not able to use the variable data **`n`** out side $get() block and when i use alerts to show **`n`** first outside alert is showing and then alert inside $get() block is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because **$.get** like **$.ajax** is asynchronous call. Code after it will not wait for it to finish, that's why alert outside of **$.get** is triggered before alert found in **$.get**. Basically $.get call will trigger and rest of code will continue to work, when $.get finishes it will trigger its inner callback function.

You need to append new content inside **$.get** call.

If you really need to make it synchronous you will need to use **$.ajax** function and set async parameter to false. But be warned, in this case your complete page execution will halt, at least until **$.ajax** finishes.

Comment: i tried appending the contents inside by putting `$("body").append(n);` inside the **$get** but it is not working.

Comment: Then you need to find out why it's not working, I gave you answer to your current question. Tell me first, have you checked did you received any response from $.get, basically is template empty or does it hold some content?

Comment: Plus I probably know your problem. You need to learn how jQuery objects work. First move this lines: var device_data={ device_id:device_id }; out side of the function. At the same time, inside a function, set this: device_data.device_id = device_id . You cant pass parameter to function expecting it will magically get written into an object.

Comment: $get is working i am getting the data from template,but only problem is not able to append the data to the body outside $get.

Comment: I told you, you CAN'T append data outside of the $.get. Google what asynchronous call means. When you alert n inside $.get function, do you see anything?

Comment: ya i understand it now. Actually my problem is to get the contents from template file. can you tell me any other alternative to do this.

Comment: First answer my last question, do you see content when you trigger alert(n) inside $.get function?

Comment: yes i can see the contents when i trigger alert(n) inside $.get.

Comment: Excellent, lets do this step by step. Tell me what browser are you using? And do you know how to use Web developer Tools inside Firefox or Chrome (if you are using it)?

Comment: i am using Chrome and i know how to use developer tools

Comment: Excellent, now move this line: $("body").append(n); to $.get function, after alert. When code executes use web developer tools and look if you page is now inside a  BODY.

Comment: Excelent now move this line: $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#videodiv_"+device_id ); at the end of $.get function. And before you test anything tell me have you moved object device_data outside of mentioned function?

Comment: i have moved `$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#videodiv_"+device_id );` at the end of $.get function now it is working fine.

Comment: You see it was easy :D

Comment: You can move it, but that's beyond the point. It's working so we can skip it.

Comment: Np bro, don't forget to accept this answer, we feed on reputation ;)